# ubuntu application publishing

Tags: application-development

I am having some trouble publishing my first application. I created the application using 'quickly' and have set up my own ppa, registered a fingerprint, gone through the gpg email security steps, signed the code of conduct agreement etc.

After I have generated my application using 'quickly package'
I then proceed to try and upload it to my ppa using the command:

```
dput ppa:sdpagent/packages upload-screenshot_0.1_i386.changes
```

This then produces the following error output:

```
Checking signature on .changes
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: the signature could not be verified.
Please remember that the signature file (.sig or .asc)
should be the first file given on the command line.
No signature on /home/stuart/Dropbox/Python/ubuntu_apps/upload-screenshot_0.1_i386.changes.
```

Please could someone advise me on where I should find and put this gpg/sig data? perhaps I needed to add some options to the 'quickly package' command?

Regards,
Stuart

Comment: The problem is that your package data is not signed. I do not know how to do this with Quickly. Maybe you can check `quickly help` on how to sign it. As far as I know, there is a `quickly` command to upload it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually I use `quickly release` or `quickly submitubuntu`.  The latter makes it install in /opt/extras.ubuntu.com which is required for post-release submission for the software center through http://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com

```
$ quickly help ubuntu-application release
Usage: quickly release [--ppa <ppa | group/ppa>] [release-version] [comments]

Posts a release of your project to a PPA on launchpad so that
users can install the application on their system.

Before running 'quickly release', you should: create your account
and a project page on http://launchpad.net.
You also have to add a PPA to your launchpad account.

Name, email, and version will be automatically changed in setup.py and
bzr will tag the current source with the new version number.

If not specified, the new version number will be 'YEAR.MONTH[.RELEASE]'.

For example, the third release in July 2010 would be versioned 10.07.2.

You may want to make sure that the description and long description in
setup.py are up to date before releasing.

You can optionally run 'quickly package' and test your package to make
sure it installs as expected.
```

Comment: Thanks Ian!
yes 'quickly release' was the trick. Had to jump through a couple more hurdles but managed it due to all the helpful output texts. Spent more time figuring out how to publish than making the application itself. Have never set up launchpad etc before. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad it worked for you!  If you could please mark the question as answered, that would be great!